# Shareable log file in C - how?

Tags: c, logging, global

I've got a project comprised of multiple C files (display.cpp, main.cpp, ...). I'd like to have a single log file which I can write to from these various programs which comprise the project. How do I implement and reference a globally-accessible file? I'm new to C but I know how to define and use (open, read, write, close) a file within the context of a single file. But how do I implement a shareable file?

For example, what kind of a declaration is required here to make the file globally accessible (i.e., to set it up for global accessibility). And how is this declaration propagated to other files which will access this log file. Do I put a declaration and/or related statement in a header file which each file that will write to the log includes? I would think hat there would be a fairly straightforward, basic answer. I realize that things can be done in many alternate ways. I'm just trying to implement basic functionality. That it is a log file which I want to implement should be irrelevant. I just want a shared writable file.

Do I simply open the log file, write to it, and then immediately close the file, and repeat the open/write(append)/close process each time I want to write to the log file, as in the code below. Seems like a lot of overhead. I guess I can put all this code in a function I call will the data to be written to the log file. Am I correct about the overhead? Does this sound like the approach to use?

```
FILE *myfile2;
errno_t errorCode = fopen_s(&myfile2, "C://Users/richard/Desktop/cTestbed2015/test22.txt", "a");
if (myfile2== NULL)
{
    printf("myfile2 does not exist \n");
}
fprintf(myfile2, "Posting from readfile.cpp\n");
fclose(myfile2);
```

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: Write to it in append mode, and each application will simply add to what the other ones wrote. If you want to be even more careful, use file locks.

Comment: You could instead use `syslog` if you're running on Unix.

Comment: I understand appending, but how do I reference the file from multiple files which want to write to the log?

Comment: ..not running on Unix.

Comment: Mentioning what plaform you *do* run on may be more helpful than a list of "not that"s. Opening the file, writing, then closing seems most safe. Use file locks if your platform allows it.

Comment: ..is it as simple as opening up the same log file in each of the submitting files?

Comment: Sorry. Newbie here. Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop.

Comment: Opening and writing to log is working in first file. Duplicated the code in the second file and got error. Got Expression (sring-Null)

Comment: Please don't attempt to post code in a comment. Comments are *transient* on Stack Overflow, and only meant for asking clarification. You can **[edit]** your own post and add code to it. Make sure to make it *part of your question*, i.e., no need to add "Edit" in the text. See also [How do I format my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) in the [help]. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the short [Introductory Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) some time!

Comment: @Jongware Will do. Thanks.

Comment: As far as keeping it simple, I think your method of opening, appending, and closing, is not bad. I don't really recommend having multiple programs use the same log file, because of the potential for them to both try to modify it at the same time. In the best case scenario, you have to wait and try again when you can't edit the file, because another program is using it.

Answer (score 1):

"Do I put a declaration and/or related statement in a header file which each file that will write to the log includes?"

That is a pretty simple solution. Instantiate your `FILE* myLogFile` variable in any of the source files and initialize it to NULL.

When to open the file? You can either open it in main, or probably better, write a getter function getLogFile() that checks if myLogFile is NULL, opens it. To make all accesses to the log file go through this function, dont declare the FILE variable in a header file but only the getter function . You then store the FILE variable as a static variable inside the getter function, not as a global variable:

```
FILE* getLogFile()
{ static FILE* myLogFile = NULL;
  if(myLogFile == NULL)
  { myLogFile = fopen(...);
    if(myLogFile == NULL) { ... } // failure to open
  }
   return myLogFile;
}
```

I would opt for this method unless there is some additional constraints. For example, since you say the question is not only about log files but ANY shared functionality, you might have to think about thread safety if you have a multi-threaded application.